# is it possible to migrate applications from udeploy to xldeploy environment?

Tags: deployment, udeploy, xl-deploy

I would like to migrate applications from udeploy tool to xldeploy for deploying into lower environments, will it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes. But it will require some work to setup your package (like defining a `deployit-manifest.xml`) and configuring XL Deploy to connect with your infrastructure.
So there's no automated conversion between udeploy and XL Deploy.

Comment: Thank your Joris, I have an issue during websphere discover exection, I am getting an error, could you please help me !

Comment: This is a different issue. Could you please create a different question for it and provide as much info as possible?